# Iterate Through a Form with JavaScript to Get Selected Multi-Select, DropDown, and Checkbox Items

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm trying to iterate through a form using javascript but am having an issue getting the values for the following form fields: Checkboxes, Multi-Select selected items, Dropdown selected items. Here is the code that I have:

```
var fdata = new FormData();
$("form input[type='text']").each(function (x, y) {
    fdata.append($(y).attr("name"), $(y).val());
});
$("form input[type='hidden']").each(function (x, y) {
    fdata.append($(y).attr("name"), $(y).val());
});

for (var pair of fdata.entries()) {
    alert(pair[0] + ', ' + pair[1]);
}
```

Currently all checkboxes return as FALSE.

I would want the multi-selects to be formatted the SAME way the FormCollection object formats them. i.e. the formcollection formats the multi-selected values like this: [Users,{L012,L013}] I wouldn't want it to be formatted as [Users,{L012}],[Users,{L013}]

Here is a list of the fields I am having issues getting data for (note that I did not include all of the code for each of these form elements):

```
<select id="coe" multiple="multiple" name="Coes">
    <option value="@item.Value" selected>
</select>
<select asp-for="IssueData.AreaId" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.FaList, "AreaId", "Area"))">
</select>
<select id="owners" multiple="multiple" name="Owners">
    <option value="@item.Value" selected>
</select>
<select asp-for="IssueData.originating" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.pList, "pId", "pName"))">
</select>
<select id="affected" multiple="multiple" name="Affected">
     <option value="@item.Value" selected>
</option>
@Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => modelItem.IssueData.internalExternal, new[]
    { new SelectListItem { Text = " ", Value = "" },
<select asp-for="IssueData.VendorID" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.VendorList, "VendorID", "Vendor"))">
</select>
@Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => modelItem.IssueData.inOperation, new[] {
@Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => modelItem.IssueData.delay, new[] {
<select asp-for="IssueData.QuarterID" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.QuarterList, "QuarterId", "Quarter"))">
<input id="revisit" asp-for="@Model.IssueData.revisit" class="revisit" type="checkbox" onclick="onSelectChange(this)" />
```

Comment: *Currently all checkboxes return as FALSE.* Please provide your current code regarding checkboxes.

Comment: @Lain - The code above is all of my code.